# Getting a PDF from another API

Tags: java, angular, scala, pdf

How can I get a PDF from another API through my own API then to the front for downloading by the user.

All I get now is a blank page.

The back is in Scala and when I println the file, I get it in a String.

In the front, I get the blob and use that function to download it :

```
onDownload(invoice) {
var mediaType = 'application/pdf';
this.invoices.downloadInvoice(invoice.id).subscribe((file: Blob) => {
  const fileName = invoice.number;
  var blob = new Blob([file], { type: mediaType });
  const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  FileSaver.default(fileUrl, fileName.toString());
}), err => {
  console.error(err);
 }
}
```

The back is using Play and the WebService to get the file from another API but I can only receive it as a string it seems. Should I try to store him on the server then serve it to the front ?

Answer (score 0):

Which scala-server used? And what does the path/API return?

> Should I try to store him on the server then serve it to the front

This is the sure-shot way of making it work. For eg: If using akka-server, save the incoming file in some temporary location (say /tmp), and use akka-route  `getFromFile` to server the file to front-end. Every server will have an equivalent of this.

If we want to bypass file-saving, we need to trick/hack the client into thinking that the incoming `string` is actually a file. I am not sure if your server will allow this, but you can try by passing the same http-headers. For this, create a simple API to send some PDF, check all the headers received on the client side, and then make sure your hacky way sends the same http-headers.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I finally fixed it by saving the file on the server, served it to the front and deleted it afterwards.